# The safety of direct SQL-requests in Joomla templates/views

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, mysql, virtuemart, mvc

I need to change the ordering of which the products are displayed on the Virtuemart category page. The files `models/product.php` and `tables/products.php` are too complicated for me to put the changes in them. So I decided to use direct SQL-requests in `views/category/default.php` (if more precisely in `templates/my_template/html/com_virtuemart/category/default.php`) like:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('a.virtuemart_product_id');
$query->from('#__virtuemart_product_categories AS a');
$query->where($db->quoteName('virtuemart_category_id')." = ".$db->quote($this->category->virtuemart_category_id));
$query->select('b.product_in_stock, c.product_price');
$query->join('LEFT', '#__virtuemart_products AS b ON b.virtuemart_product_id = a.virtuemart_product_id');
$query->join('LEFT', '#__virtuemart_product_prices AS c ON c.virtuemart_product_id = a.virtuemart_product_id');
$query->order('b.product_in_stock DESC, c.product_price DESC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$sortedProducts = $db->loadObjectList();
...
```

It's not the only case when I needed to use direct SQL-requests in some view(s) or in template(s).

**But to what extent is such direct way safe and how to protect it to the maximum extent possible?**

Comment: Safe like from a hacker perspective or safe from messing things up?

Comment: I don't know exactly all the perspectives there can be a danger from. So from any possible one

Answer (score 4):

Joomla is built on the MVC design pattern, so querying the db from a view is bad practice. But with your scenario, let's consider a few alteratives:

- *changing the model*: this makes no sense: you can't change a model you don't own, or you'll be tied to applying your changes with every new release; additionally, you mention it's overly complicated;
- *query from the template*: your current solution, not scalable, doesn't leverage Joomla cache properly.
- **create a model**: (or a helper), put it inside the appropriate VM folder, and invoke it from your view: definitely the most attractive solution: no overhead, simpler code, additionally you leverage Joomla features including: **cache** and proper design pattern use with separation of concerns, making maintenance easier for your future self.

To consider your current solution:

- You are **not** introducing any vulnerability: your code properly escapes the query parameters so no unexpected results can come from there;
- You are not following best practices; should your queries become more complex, your code will be harder to maintain; other developers may find it slightly harder to find your work;
- The code cannot use the Joomla cache properly (only page cache will work); with a small shop, no problems; but with a larger number of products performances will be affected

**Conclusions**

If your work is a proof of concept, go with your current solution; if this is a live website, invest a bit of your time to create a helper or model where you'll code your queries.  You'll gain flexibility, re-usability (if two views require the same data, you don't need to duplicate code), and save some time in the future.

Comment: @stckvrw this answer seems "acceptable" to me, but your question appears abandoned.  If this answer offers you satisfactory support, please award the green tick.  If not, please ask for further explanation from this user.